# Skip maximum timestamp and fetch others

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle11g

Table A has Registration_id and Client_No.

Table B has Last_Login_Email,Last_Login_Mobile and Last_Login_OFX timestamp of each Registration_id.

My requirement is below :-
Fetch all Registration_id's which are tied to multiple Client_no and out of these skip Registration_id with maximum time-stamp and fetch others.

Example:-

Table A

```
Registration_id       Client_No     
AAA                      111      
BBB                      111    
CCC                      111     
DDD                      444     
EEE                      555     
FFF                      666     
GGG                      666
```

So in above table AAA,BBB,CCC are tied to same Client_no which is 111.Also FFF,GGG tied to same CLient_no which is 666.

So these Registration_id (AAA,BBB,CCC) and (FFF,GGG) qualified for first part of my condition.

Now out of 1st set of Registration_id which are tied to same Client_no i want to skip the Registration_id with maximum time-stamp and fetch other.And same for 2nd set and so on.

Example: (for typing convinicence i have used Date instead of timestamp in below example)

Table B

Table B                DD/MM/YYYY           DD/MM/YYYY             DD/MM/YYYY

```
Registration_id      Last_Login_Email     Last_Login_Mobile     Last_Login_OFX     
AAA                    01/12/2017             02/12/2017              01/11/2017     
BBB                    01/01/2018             02/01/2018             03/01/2018     
CCC                    01/11/2017             02/11/2017             03/11/2017     
DDD                    01/01/2018             02/01/2018             03/01/2018     
EEE                    21/01/2018             22/01/2018             23/01/2018     
FFF                    12/01/2018             13/01/2018              14/01/2018     
GGG                   29/01/2018             28/01/2018             31/01/2018
```

Note:- In above table B we dont have to do anything with DDD and EEE as they are not qualified under 1st part of condition.I have given in above table just for sake of completeness.

Lets take 1st set here which is AAA,BBB,CCC

From Table B 
         Maximum-Timestamp out of Last_Login_Email,Last_Login_Mobile
         andLast_Login_OFX

AAA   02/12/2017

BBB   03/01/2018

CCC   03/11/2017

Above we can see maximum timestamp is for BBB(out of AAA,BBB,CCC) so i want to skip BBB here and fetch AAA and CCC.

Same goes to other set which is FFF,GGG

From Table B 
        Maximum-Timestamp out of Last_Login_Email,Last_Login_Mobile and 
         Last_Login_OFX

FFF   14/01/2018

GGG   31/01/2018

Above we can see maximum timestamp is for GGG so i need to skip GGG and fetch FFF.

So my overall logic should fetch AAA,CCC and FFF.

Hope i am clear with my requiremet.

Comment: OK, so what have you tried?  Also please tag with one database.

Comment: Hi,i am really not getting any clue how to achieve this.Any help here is highly appreciated.Also please let me know if not clear with requirement.

Comment: in Oracle, and pretend salary is your timestamp/date with
max_sal AS 
  ( select /*+ materialize */ 
    max(salary) great from employees )
SELECT
   *
FROM
   employees,
   max_sal
where
   salary < (great);

Comment: I dont think this will work for my entire senario.Can you please explain ?

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do that.

As you didn't provide test case, I was - in turn - too lazy to type full names. Though, you explained it quite well, thank you for that.

- TA and TB are your A and B tables
- REG_ID is your REGISTRATION_ID
- QUALI_1 and QUALI_2 represent your two qualification steps

Here we go:

```
SQL> with quali_1 as
  2  (select reg_id, client_no
  3   from ta
  4   where client_no in (select client_no
  5                       from ta
  6                       group by client_no
  7                       having count(distinct reg_id) > 1)
  8  ),
  9  quali_2 as
 10  (select b.reg_id, q.client_no,
 11     greatest(b.ll_email, b.ll_mobile, b.ll_ofx) ll_max
 12   from tb b join quali_1 q on b.reg_id = q.reg_id
 13  )
 14  select reg_id
 15  from quali_2
 16  where (client_no, ll_max) not in
 17        (select client_no, max(ll_max) ll_max
 18         from quali_2
 19         group by client_no)
 20  order by reg_id;

REG
---
aaa
ccc
fff

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks LittleFoot i will try your solution and let you know if it works for me.